# Elasticsearch search multiple fields and return results if field value is in array of values

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello i am trying to create multi-select search. So for example i have to dropdown select input fields.

So each single dropdown should be able to send more than 1 value or just 1.

status: ['CONF', 'DNF']
id: [1, 2]

And i Have Records

```
 |id|status     |
 ----------------
 |1 | DNF       |
 |2 | CONF      |
 |3 | START     |
 |4 | FINISH    |
```

So if i send [1,2] and [DNF, START]

Just return record with id 1

if i send [3,4] and [DNF, CONF]

Do not return anything

I have tried something like this

```
"bool": {
      "match": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entry_status": "CONF"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entry_status": "DNF"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entry_id": "1"
          }
        },
      ]
    }
```

but No luck. Any idea how to solve whits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it possible to do this with query string

"query_string": {
"query": "(entry_status:DQ OR entry_status:DNF OR entry_status:WITHDRAWN) AND (entry_id:4 OR entry_id:2)",
}